# expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected) Expected number of calls: 1 Received number of calls: 0

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

First If it is very easy ,I am sorry It is my first time to write unit test.I write my code to test if fn is called once under condition

```
it("fill shownCategories when state not compare", () => {

  component.state != 'compare'
  if (component.state != 'compare') {

    const filterShownCategoriesSpy = spyOn(component, 'FilterShownCategories').and.returnValue(
      [{
        hiddenVariants: 0,
        id: 187910,
        lang: "de",
        name: "AMG/Exterieur",
        plId: 5389,
        refId: "1015001000",
        type: "AMG",
        visibleVariants: 5
      }, {
        hiddenVariants: 0,
        id: 187911,
        lang: "de",
        name: "AMG/Interieur",
        plId: 5389,
        refId: "1015002000",
        type: "AMG",
        visibleVariants: 7,
      }]
    )
    expect(filterShownCategoriesSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.shownCatgeories).toEqual([]);
  }
});

public addFirstTable() {
  console.log("addFirstTable");
  //awel mara showncategories gaya fadya a lazm amlaha lw state msh edit
  if (this.state != "compare") {
    // this.shownCatgeories = this.allCatigories.map(a => ({ ...a }));
    this.shownCatgeories = this.FilterShownCategories();
    console.log("shownCatgeories if state is not compare", this.shownCatgeories);
  }
}
```

output
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

```
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It's unclear how the snippet you posted is related to the test, and it's unclear  what's the purpose of `component.state != 'compare'
if (component.state != 'compare') {` in the test. The test fails because between `spyOn` and `expect(filterShownCategoriesSpy)` there should be the code that calls `filterShownCategories` in order for the test to pass, and currently there's none, it's certainly not called.

Answer (score 0):

In this first of all you are assigning value to state wrong way.

Change this

```
 component.state != 'compare';
```

to

```
 component.state = 'any state';
```

And add below line

```
component.addFirstTable();
```

before

```
expect(filterCategoriesSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: If this works please accept this answer too. Thanks.